# Platform or API to allow purchasing and payment to owner

Tags: api, payment-gateway

I am looking for the easiest platform or API to integrate into my site that would allow users to sell goods and get paid for them. I would, of course, take a small percentage of the payment. Hoping for something that is usable from python, though php would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need split payments. I think only [Paypal](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1414) currently offers that.